# Firebase realtime database is not connecting

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Iam trying to use firebase real-time database. I have set rules to true and in my project added all required dependencies and also internet permission. My mobile is very well connected to the wifi.

When I tried to use write the data then it's not working. So I checked the status as per documentation and it's showing dB is not connected to my app.

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connected");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "not connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listener was cancelled");
    }
});
```

Am I doing anything wrong hwre?

Appreciate help.

PD

Comment: Can you clarify " it's not working"? Does your `onDataChange` or `onCancelled` get called?

Comment: In the onCancelled method, use a log or a Toast to display the error

Comment: Yes but it goes to not connected.

Comment: What do you mean by "goes to not connected"? Does onDataChange or onCancelled fire?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the **Query**

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = connectedRef.child("info/connected");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected");
        } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "not connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listener was cancelled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Now it is not even entering into the event listener.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved by recreating database and connecting again to the app. Thank you for the answers.